# how to solve flutter.gradle and flutter.bat error? 'D:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1052'

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

/D:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth_platform_interface-4.2.4/lib/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase_auth.dart:244:34: Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'UserCredentialPlatform' doesn't allow null.

- 'UserCredentialPlatform' is from 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_user_credential.dart' ('/D:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth_platform_interface-4.2.4/lib/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_user_credential.dart').
  Future createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
  ^
  2

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'D:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1052
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'D:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

### BUILD FAILED in 1m 56s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

Know i am getting this
/D:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth_platform_interface-4.2.4/lib/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase_auth.dart:244:34:
Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'UserCredentialPlatform' doesn't allow null.

- 'UserCredentialPlatform' is from 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_user_credential.dart'
  ('/D:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth_platform_interface-4.2.4/lib/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_user_credential.dart ').
  Future createUserWithEmailAndPassword(

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest version of package, flutter, dart ! Because almost all famous packages had been updated to null safety !

Comment: hi thanks for you reply. i am already using latest version.                                                           firebase_auth: ^1.3.0
  firebase_core: ^1.2.1

Comment: add the code where you are getting error ?

Comment: bro I don't know how it's done or it's working now I have deleted the flutter sdk and download it again. and it's working know

Comment: Ok ! All the best

Answer (score 0):

Change the language of the device to English if it is not
Then open Android Studio and open the application on the default device

It will work with you with ease
You can return to your favorite language in the device after that